# opencv pixels have different coordinates than shown pixels

Tags: opencv, pixel

EDIT: solved, i had to access the pixel by using

```
    (int)bw.at<uchar>(r,c)
```

For a project at school i have to detect a ball and calculate it's position. I do this with color segmentation: with inRange i check for the color of the ball and i get a binary image as result. At least i assume it's binary because the picture is black and white when i display it.

I now try to get the position of the ball by simply taking the average of the x and the y coordinates of all the detected pixels. The strange thing is that the y values are correct but the x values are completely wrong.

Here is my code:

```
    int k = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    for(int c = 0; c < bw.cols; c++){
    for(int r = 0; r < bw.rows; r++){

            if(bw.at<int>(r,c) != 0){
                x += c;
                y += r;
                cout << "x: " << c << " y: " << r << endl;
                k++;
                myfile << 1;
            }else{
                myfile << 0;
            }
        }
        myfile << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
    bal.set_pos(x/k,y/k);
```

I print each pixel's x and y coordinate and the y coordinates are right but the x coordinates are grouped in 4 different groups, the first group has values around 88, second group values around 248, 3rd group 408, 4th group 569. They should be between 350 and 360 however.

Comment: With your conventions, y corresponds to the rows and x to the columns. In your code, you should replace `x += r` by `x += c` (same for y). Then, you will have a problem with the y coordinate instead ;-) and you should check if the direction of the coordinaite axis is not flipped (images have (0,0) at the upper left corner, while sometimes people work with (0,0) at the lower left).

Comment: That was a typo. The direction of the axis is ok. 
I don't get how this is happening, when i show the picture it shows a nice white dot, when i look at the txt file i get 4 seperate dots :s, so weird.